# How to remove the [ and ] in a string result

Tags: javascript, regex

example output: `[EU Ecolabel (EU Flower),Cradle to Cradle (C2C) - Gold]`

`str.replace(/,/g, "||" );` works fine to replace the comma with a double-pipe symbol

I just cannot get the 2 brackets removed with: `return str2.replace(/(\[|\]),/," ");`

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!
HJ

```
function main(args, values) {
   var str = inriverctx.GetExtraRelatedEntityFieldDisplayValue("Certification","CertificationName","","CertificationItems","0");
   var str2 = str.replace(/,/g, "||" );
   return str2.replace(/(\\[|\\]),/," ");
}
```

Comment: If you replaces all commas in the first replace, then there cannot be any comas for the second `/(\\[|\\]),/`.

Comment: Also, double escapes `\\ ` seem erroneous there.

Comment: Why are you only replacing `[` and `]` that are followed by `,`? Is that a typo?

Comment: Where are the brackets coming from in the first place? If this was originally JSON, maybe you should use `JSON.parse()` to get an array, and then format that as you want.

Comment: So maybe you mean `return str2.replace(/(\[|\])/," ");`

Comment: @barmar indeed it's a JSON

Comment: Then just use `JSON.parse(json).join("||")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
str.replace(/,/g, "||" ).replace(/[\][]/g, '')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/iml4C0/2).

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\][]                    any character of: ']', '['
```